# Angular - Conditional attribute of an element

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, grid, conditional-statements

I am using [ion-grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) which is based on [Bootstrap's grid system](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/). Here is a simplified version of the code I use for a different range of elements:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let task of allTasks">
    <ion-col *ngIf="task.author === this.currentUser" offset-3 col-9 class="task">
       <div>{{task.description}}</div>
     </ion-col>
  </ion-row>                                                              
</ion-grid>
```

My ion-grid has **12** columns. `offset-3` will basically push the element to the rightmost part of the column. However, I wish to conditionally change this attribute in two ways:

1. If a specific condition holds, do not apply `offset-3` to this element. What would be the correct syntax for this: `myCondition ? "offset-3" : ""`
2. How can I dynamically change `offset-{value}`? Say if I assign `col-auto` to the element above, how can I change **{value}** of `offset-{value}` so that it is no less than **3** or is larger? E.g. `col-auto` assigns `col-6` to the element, change `offset-{value}` to `offset-6` - or simply push the element to the rightmost part of the column.

I am not sure if **2.** is actually possible to implement, but any workaround which will have the same result I desire, will be enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your component create an @input attribute then you can pass the value to your html;
offset{{inputValue}}
Just maybe do more logic in your component. and pass the value to the html so that you retrieve the value before it gets to set in the HTML.

example;

```
your components.ts;

  @Input() value: string;


You create a new method lets say;

getOffsetValue() {

if (x === foo) {
this.value = '1';
}else {
this.value = '2';
}
return this.value
}

ngOnInit()

// call method

getOffsetValue();

So now you have a data on the value attribute

in your HTML;
offSet{{this.value}}
```

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to provide a sample code to do this? I have tried the following: `<ion-col *ngIf="task.author === this.currentUser" offset{{this.inputValue}} col-9 class="task">` but it simply resulted in this error: `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'offset{{this.inputValue}}' is not a valid attribute name.`.

Comment: Typing this on phone so might look ugly, but hope you get the point
- Tried to provide a pseudo example